# seaborn theme is not displayed in samsung monitors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to enhance my matplotlib plots.

Although the plots seem to be properly generated, I can't see the theme in any of my two samsungs displays.
If I send the plot (or a screenshot of it) to another computer, the seaborn theme appears.

This is the plot saved from matplotlib:
[image: plot saved from matplotlib]

This is what I see on my desktop (**white** background and **no** grid):
[[image: desktop2]

This is what I see on my notebook (grayish background and grid):
[image: notebook]

To generate the plot, I used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("darkgrid")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)

ax.plot([-1, 1], [-1, 1], label="Line")
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Versions:

- ubuntu 20.04
- python 3.8.13
- seaborn 0.11.2
- matplotlib 3.5.1

My desktop displays:

- LC24F390FHLMZD (samsung)
- LF24T350FHLMZD (samsung)

Note: when taking a screenshot on my desktop, I can briefly see the theme

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you see if you attach the monitor to the laptop and plot to the monitor?

Comment: https://community.uxmastery.com/t/cant-see-grey-on-some-monitors/5515/17 Look at the grayscale image in the 9th comment

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney if I attach the monitor to the laptop, I can see the theme

Comment: So maybe a driver setting. Doesn’t seem like a programming issue though.

Comment: Curious ... if you go to the seaborn docs do the images look normal?

Comment: after i plug my monitor back to my desktop, i can properly see the themes (in my two monitors - weird). @TrentonMcKinney